# how do I start a command in a terminal as if I'd opened the terminal and typed the command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal, gnome-terminal

I spend a lot of time opening terminals and typing commands in them.

```
$ gnome-terminal
(change mouse focus to new terminal)
$ reset && clear && tail -F ~/file_that_grows
```

every so often, I'll find myself going to that window and killing the process with control-C, and then restarting it. In fact I'll usually alias the reset && .... bit to something more typable, like rctf.

How can I automate the first bit of the process? The best I can do so far is

```
gnome-terminal --title rctf -e 'tail -F ~/.bashrc'
```

But there are various problems with this. Firstly the ~ doesn't get expanded, so the file isn't found. Secondly, when the command is over, the terminal exits.

Is there any way to automatically start a terminal exactly as if I'd opened it and then typed something? (Extra points if you can get the command in the history so that it can be restarted with up-arrow ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind storing your command in a file, you can abuse the `--rcfile` option in `bash`. For example, using the following script to store your command(s):

```
[me@home]$ cat $HOME/.term-rcfile  
. ~/.bashrc         # chain in the standard rc file
tail -F ~/.bashrc   # command to run
```

You can then do:

```
xterm -e "bash --rcfile $HOME/.term-rcfile -i"
```

Should also work for gnome-terminal:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash --rcfile $HOME/.term-rcfile -i"
```

---

> "(Extra points if you can get the command in the history so that it can be restarted with up-arrow )."

I can't see how to do that automatically, but if your run:

```
history -r ~/.term-rcfile
```

once you're in the new terminal (or whenever you want/need), entries from the file will be appended to your history (without running them) and you would then have access to them as you would normal history entries.

Answer (score 3):

For interactive programs, I use:

```
    xterm -e 'sh -c "vi $HOME/foo.txt; sh"'
```

The `sh -c` means that variables in my command string are substituted
and the `sh` at the end means that a shell is started after I finish
with `vi` instead of closing the terminal window.

For a non-interactive program like `tail` that can only be stopped by pressing CTRL-C
to send SIGINT to the process, I use the shell `trap` built-in to be sure that a
shell is run if the user presses CTRL-C instead of closing the terminal window:

```
    xterm -e sh -c 'trap sh SIGINT; tail -f $HOME/foo.txt'
```

Comment: That does do what I want for vi, but with tail, the Ctrl-C to kill the program also kills the xterm.  (using xterm -e 'sh -c "tail -F ~/.bashrc; sh"' )

Answer (score 1):

Use $HOME variable instead of the tilde.

```
gnome-terminal --title rctf -e "tail -F $HOME/.bashrc"
```

Comment: Long ago but still  interesting. I want to open gnome-terminal after a special usb device is inserted. I exported the display in my sh-file which is invoked from the udev rule and in it i issue gnome-terminal. But i want that this is the only script, printing some Info on the new terminal and awaiting user's  input by read. Interactive.It works when I spawn gnome-terminal without arguments,  passing title does nothing, x and e just close the window immediately. What could be a proper way?